# Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, probability

> > I'm having trouble establishing this identity below.
> >     Suppose $Y$ and $Z$ are random variables on $(\Omega,F,P)$ and $Y \in L^1$. Suppose $Z$ is bounded and let $G \subset F$ be a sub-$\sigma$-field. Show that $$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|G)Z)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Z|G)Y).$$
> >     Is there a way I can attack it using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $$\mathbb{E}(XY|G)^2 \leq \mathbb{E}(X^2|G)\mathbb{E}(Y^2|G)?$$ 
> >     Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the relevance of $X \in L^1$?

Comment: @PEV: I think $X = Y$ is intended. You need *some* condition on $Y$ in order for the conditional expectation to be defined. By Hölder, the conditions $Y \in L^1$ and $Z \in L^\infty$ ensure that both sides of the desired equality are in fact finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Cauchy-Schwarz can be of any help because $L^1 \supsetneqq L^2$, usually. Since $\mathbb{E}(Y|G)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Z|G)$ are $G$-measurable we have $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|G)Z|G) = \mathbb{E}(Y|G)\mathbb{E}(Z|G) = \mathbb{E}(Y\mathbb{E}(Z|G)|G)$. Now take  (unconditional) expectation on both sides.

Comment: @Theo: what about the boundedness of $Z$?

Comment: @Eric: Sorry, what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Theo: I guess I'd like to know why $Z$ was assumed to be bounded? Thanks.

Comment: @Eric: As I said in my comment to PEV above, the conditions $Y \in L^1$ and $Z \in L^\infty$ ensure via Hölder that all the functions appearing in my answer are integrable and thus their (conditional) expectations are defined and finite. If you want me to elaborate, I should know under what conditions exactly conditional expectations is defined in your course.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks very much. I get it now.

Comment: @Eric: Very good! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Both are equal to $E(E(Y|G)E(Z|G))$.