# Questions about conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory

This comes from page 2 of *General Theory of Markov Processes* by Michael Sharpe, with some changes in notation.

Suppose 
$$P(A_1\cap A_2\,|\,  {\cal F}_{=t} )= P(A_1 \,|\,  {\cal F}_{=t} )P( A_2\,|\,  {\cal F}_{=t} )$$
for all $A_1\in {\cal F}_{\leq t}$ and $A_2\in {\cal F}_{\geq t}$.
Using well known properties of conditional expectations, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(A_1\cap A_2)
&=&P(P(A_1\cap A_2\ |\  {\cal F}_{=t}))\cr
&=&P\left( P(A_1\  |\  {\cal F}_{=t})\ P(A_2 \ | \ {\cal F}_{=t})  \right)\cr
&=&P(P(A_2\ |\  {\cal F}_{=t}) ; A_1).
\end{eqnarray*}

My question is by what property of conditional expectations, we can have $$ P\left( P(A_1\  |\  {\cal F}_{=t})\ P(A_2 \ | \ {\cal F}_{=t})  \right)
= P(P(A_2\ |\  {\cal F}_{=t}) ; A_1)?$$

What is the general form for the property of conditional expectation?

Any reference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29090/conditional-expectation/29091#29091

Comment: @Byron: I still don't understand your reply there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every sigma-algebra G and every (suitably integrable) random variables X and Y such that Y is G-measurable, one has E(XY)=E(E(X|G)Y). This is one of the two conditions that characterize E(X|G), the other one being that E(X|G) is G-measurable. In particular, for every event A, E(Y;A)=E(P(A|G)Y).

Apply this to G your sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}_{=t}$, A the event $A_1$ and Y the conditional probability of $A_2$ conditionally on G.

Note: in your post five Ps should be Es.

Comment: Thank you! In definition of E(X|G), I remember it is E(X)=E(E(X|G); A) for any A in G. So is E(XY)=E(E(X|G)Y) for any G-measurable random variable Y really part of its definition? Why is E(XY)=E(E(X|G)Y) true?

Comment: It is equivalent to ask that E(X;A)=E(E(X|G);A) for every A in G or to ask that E(XY)=E(E(X|G)Y) for every (bounded) G-measurable random variable Y. The latter implies logically the former but it is a standard exercise to prove that the two are in fact equivalent.

Comment: From the former to the latter, is it proved by using simple functions to approximate Y when Y is nonnegative?

Comment: Yes. This is called a functional monotone class theorem, see http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/ProofOfFunctionalMonotoneClassTheorem.html